# System.create error in F# Akka.NET

Tags: f#, json.net, akka.net

The following line:

`let system = System.create "MyActorSystem" <| Configuration.load ()`

... produces this output in the F# Interactive window:

`Binding session to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'...
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DiscriminatedUnionConverter' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
   at Akka.Serialization.NewtonSoftJsonSerializer..ctor(ExtendedActorSystem system)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

In my project references, Newtonsoft.Json points to .\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll.  I've read that I need version 7 or above of Newtonsoft.Json for Akka.NET, so I'm not sure why I'm seeing binding for version 4.5 in the FSI output; is that a false correlation that I should just ignore?

I thought that another copy of the library file might be loading, so in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\FsiAnyCPU.exe.config`, I added:

`<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.1.0" />`

... but then I just get `error FS0192: internal error: convMethodRef: could not bind to method` in FSI.

I've tried looking in the fusion logs; binding succeeds for the Newtonsoft.Json library, so nothing fishy going on, there.

Anyone else run into this problem?

EDIT: OK so I discovered in the fusion logs that another copy of Newtonsoft.Json.dll, in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\`, was intercepting binding.  How do I prevent this without simply removing the library file from the Blend folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your not loading the Json.NET from your packages folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

write at the top of the script

`#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`

this will add the source directory on the probing paths.
your references should resolve correctly.

Comment: That doesn't work.  The CLR still binds to the wrong assembly in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\, resulting in a fatal error.  I have to remove the Newtonsoft.Json.dll library file from that folder in order for the CLR to bind to the correct assembly.  I'm looking for a way to force a bind to the correct assembly without having to do this.